# Experience certificate from my company

Tags: resignation, india, relieving-letter

I resigned from my company and had served notice period of 2 months.On my last day some how my company came to know that I have joined its competitor company. My company came to know about this and they refused to provide my experience letter and relieving email.

Further Details:
There was never anything mentioned in the signed offer letter that I should not join their competitor nor there was bond of any kind. I served the full notice period as per their norms.
Place: India

My question:

What are the ways that I can get my experience letter from the company, like file a case legally or is there any other way ?

Comment: If you would like to know any other details,Please comment I will add them to my question

Comment: @Cronax `Terminating employment (notice period, breaking the news, handing over work, reference letters, relieving letters, etc.)` from the [Help Center](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: @TerenceEden Sorry it's India, added that to my question